# Using LINQ to aggregate multiple nested elements in XDocument

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML (parsed into an XDocument):

```
XDocument nvdXML = XDocument.Parse(@"<entry id='CVE-2016-1926'>
<vulnerable-configuration id='http://www.nist.gov/'>
  <logical-test operator='OR' negate='false'>
    <fact-ref name='A'/>
    <fact-ref name='B'/>
    <fact-ref name='C'/>
  </logical-test>
</vulnerable-configuration>
<vulnerable-configuration id='http://www.nist.gov/'>
  <logical-test operator='OR' negate='false'>
    <fact-ref name='X'/>
    <fact-ref name='Y'/>
    <fact-ref name='Z'/>
  </logical-test>
</vulnerable-configuration></entry>");
```

I want to get a single collection/list of every "name" attribute for each entry (in this case there is only one entry, whose name list would consist of ['A','B','C','X','Y','Z'])

Here is the code I have:

```
var entries = from entryNodes in nvdXML.Descendants("entry")
                          select new CVE
                          {
                              //VulnerableConfigurations = (from vulnCfgs in entryNodes.Descendants(vulnNS + "vulnerable-configuration").Descendants(cpeNS + "logical-test")
                              //                            select new VulnerableConfiguration
                              //                            {
                              //                                Name = vulnCfgs.Element(cpeNS + "fact-ref").Attribute("name").Value
                              //                            }).ToList()
                              VulnerableConfigurations = (from vulnCfgs in entryNodes.Descendants("vulnerable-configuration")
                                                          from logicalTest in vulnCfgs.Descendants("logical-test")
                                                          select new VulnerableConfiguration
                                                          {
                                                              Name = logicalTest.Element("fact-ref").Attribute("name").Value
                                                          }).ToList()
                          };
```

Unfortunately, this (both commented and uncommented) query only results in VulnerableConfigurations **['A','X']**, instead of **['A','B','C','X','Y','Z']**

How do I modify my query such that every element of every list is selected (assuming there could be 1+ nested lists)?

*Note, I did search for dup's, and although there are similar questions, most are very specific, and ask for grouping/summing/manipulation, or are not related to XML parsing.*

---

Final working code (thanks to accepted answer):

```
var entries = from entryNodes in nvdXML.Descendants("entry")
                          select new CVE
                          {
                              VulnerableConfigurations = (from vulnCfgs in entryNodes.Descendants("fact-ref")
                                                          select new VulnerableConfiguration
                                                          {
                                                              Name = vulnCfgs.Attribute("name").Value
                                                          }).ToList()
                          };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this if you have only one entry:

```
var entries =(from fact in nvdXML.Descendants("fact-ref")
              select new VulnerableConfiguration
                         {
                           Name = fact.Attribute("name").Value
                         }).ToList();
```

The [Descendants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) method is going to return all descendant elements that match with that name in document order.

And if you have more than one entry and you want to return a list for each entry, you can do the following:

```
var entries =(from entry in nvdXML.Descendants("entry")
              select  entry.Descendants("fact-ref").Select(f=>f.Attribute("name").Value).ToList()
             ).ToList();
```

In this case you are going to get a list of lists (`List<List<string>>`)

### Update

Your issue was because you are flattering your query over the `logical-test` elements and in your xml you have two of them. Now in your `select` you are using `Element` method, which give you only one element, that's way you have `A` and `X`  as result, that are the first `fact-ref` elements inside your `logical-test` elements

Comment: I didnt realize you didnt need to traverse the tree to get to the nested elements. could you explain why my original query was only getting ['A', 'X']?

Comment: I updated my question to include my final code, which incorporates the parent object I was using (CVE, which holds a list of VulnerableConfigurations). your answer got me there though, so +1 and tick for you good sir.